# Integrating using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am having a problem solving this integration by changing to polar coordinates.

> Blockquote$$\int\limits_{0}^{2}\int\limits_{1}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}~dy~dx$$

As $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ is the equation of circle centered at $(1,0)$ and has a radius $1$. The limit of $y$ is $1\leq y \leq \sqrt{2x-x^2}$, so the vertical lines enter through the line $y=1$ and leave the circle at the same point.

I am not able to draw the region.

Comment: $\sqrt{2x-x^2} \le 1$  So, if you have this set-up correctly, your region is above the semi-circle and below the line...  And, we have the smaller value as the upper limit, so this result will be negative from the traditional arrangement.

Comment: To @vivekdhingra: can you confirm your limits for both integrals? For me, $1 \le x \le 2$ and $0 \le y \le \sqrt{2x-x^2}$ are more likely...

Comment: This is the region, but the limits of the inner integral need flipped (which changes the sign of the integration). https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xQ8l.png

Comment: According to me, the limit must be from  0 to $\sqrt{2x-x^2}$.